# How to access Device Manager in windows 10 using Pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I'm new to pywinauto, I'm trying to automate driver testing and I tried connecting running device manager window, but not able to get any information

I'm using `pywinauto:0.6.8` version and `python:3.7.4`

```
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Device Manager')
app.print_control_identifiers()
```

[image]

Any sample code on how to access the device manager and install / uninstall driver for devices.

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: I worked on driver testing automation as well. But it's better to use `devcon.exe` command line utility. It's included into Windows distribution and provides the most helpful commands to install/remove any driver. Some advanced driver settings can be read/set in the Windows registry using `winreg` built-in Python module. I'd suggest to start learning these tools and then ask more detailed question so we can see your efforts, not just a task "we should code for you".

Answer (score 0):

Some moments are complicated so I've prepared the code with comments about them.

```
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop

Application().start(r'mmc devmgmt.msc') # mmc.exe spawns a child process
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe') # connect to a child one
main = app.window(title='Device Manager')
#main.dump_tree()

# expand group of devices
usb_bus = main.child_window(title="Universal Serial Bus controllers", control_type="TreeItem")
usb_bus.expand()
#usb_bus.dump_tree()

# call context menu for the second USB Root Hub (found_index=1)
second_usb_root_hub = usb_bus.child_window(title="USB Root Hub", control_type="TreeItem", found_index=1)
second_usb_root_hub.click_input(button='right')

# Root of the Context menu is in the system process, so use global Desktop object.
#print(Desktop(backend="uia").windows()) # all top level windows in the system
context_menu = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title='Context')
#context_menu.dump_tree()

# Child menu items are in the mmc.exe but it doesn't matter if we have root menu object.
context_menu.child_window(title="Properties", control_type="MenuItem").invoke()
```

The `.dump_tree()` output at intermediate steps provides the most useful info about child elements. All `child_window()` specifications are just copied from `.dump_tree()` outputs.

The process ID of the elements can be checked in `Inspect.exe` (can be found in Windows SDK):

[image: USB Root Hub in Inspect.exe]

[image: Context menu in Inspect.exe]